# black screen ios simulator , xcode 11.3 on vmware

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11.3

i have installed  xcode 11.3(11C504)on mac os catalina on vmware.

after run the program simulator load and then it is black screen.

it warns "This app could not be installed at this time " and when I do " Earase all content and setting.. " suddenly SpringBoard and MigrationPluginWrapper constantly crash.

[this is screen shot of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzwSi.png)

and my plist :
[plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5NLB.png)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Xcode? & Does it happen with every code?

Comment: yes I reinstalled it and I made some project and even I deleted scenedelegate ,but it doesnt work. I used xcode 9 and that was ok until i upgrade my xcode to 11.3

Comment: Did you try another device simulator? Like instead of iPhone use iPad, etc?

Comment: yes i made an iphone 6s simulator and it didnt work ,but i only have ios 13.3 ,not other version of ios

Comment: I do mean same OS version, just like a different device simulator like iphone x or ipad, etc?

Comment: yes i did it with same os on ther device simulator , I want to tell that when I open the warning "This app could not be installed at this time " , it shows cfbundleidentifier isnt registered, is it relative?

Comment: can I have a look at your `Info.plist` file?

Comment: check out , i edited and added plist

Comment: I assume the problem could be with the OS. macOS on Windows VM sometimes have it’s weird glitches

Comment: I had highsierra version and it was fine with xcode 9 , should I get mojave version and run xcode 9 or 11 ?

Comment: how did you make a macOS VM work in Windows btw?

Comment: Also you can download the iOS 11 or any other OS version for emulator additional to the iOS13 that comes default. May be you can try with a different iOS emulator OS